# A variable set inside BOOST_FOREACH-loop is invalid outside loop, why?

Tags: c++, boost

BOOST_FOREACH invalidates a weak_ptr that resides as a member in the class GroupMember, please help me understand why.

The code below explains the error:

```
class GroupMember
{
  bool logInState;
  boost::weak_ptr<CUser> wpUser;
};

GroupMember::iterator it;

BOOST_FOREACH(EachLevel aLevel, levels)
{
  if(aLevel.exist(spUser))
  {
    it = aLevel.getIteratorToGroupMember( spUser );
    //iterator (it) is valid as well as the group member's attributes (and weak_ptr)
  }
}

//Iterator (it) seems to be valid but the weak_ptr is invalid. 
//The counter to the object is more than 10 so the weak ptr is not expired.
```

---

The code below works perfectly:

```
GroupMember::iterator it;
std::vector<EachLevel>::iterator itLevel;
for(itLevel = levels.begin(); itLevel != levels.end(); ++itLevel)
{
  if(itLevel->exist(spUser))
      it = itLevel->getIteratorToGroupMember( spUser );
}

//Here is iterator (it) valid (including the weak_ptr)
```

---

I cannot see the difference, can you?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assumed that BOOST_FOREACH is implemented like in your second code snippet, which is a wrong assumption.

Second, in your BOOST_FOREACH you iterate by value. Try by reference:

```
BOOST_FOREACH(EachLevel& aLevel, levels)
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

`EachLevel aLevel` creates a local object `aLevel` whose scope is only within the `BOOST_FOREACH`. If you take a `iterator` from this object it will be invalid outside the loop. You can change it to a reference by declaring `EachLevel& aLevel` so that no copy is created and your iterator remains valid. In the second case you are directly accessing the object without creating any copy of it, hence it works.